# Coldfusion: how to find first words between b element of a string

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to find the first words between b elements of a string.

For example:

```
<script>

myString = '<b>To be replaced</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut mattis est vitae dolor rutrum, at feugiat velit consequat. Aenean sed aliquet mi, sollicitudin tincidunt sapien.'

</script>
```

I tried this:

```
<cfset First = ListFirst(myString ,'/') />
```

My goal is to extract "To be replaced" as a variable.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
reFind('<b>(.*?)<\/b>', yourString);
```

[regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/5FbNJE/2)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer...the script above returns number 1

Comment: He probably meant `<b>` not `<bold>`. A similar change for the end tag is probably needed too

Answer (score 1):

REfind returns 1 when it finds the pattern. What you want is REReplace:

```
yourString = "<b>my string</b>";
foundString = reReplace(yourString,'<b>(.*?)<\/b>',"\1");
```

The value of foundString is now "my string".